# MS Access report with data from two tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a Clients table and a Booking table. I want to generate an Invoice with info for one client, and one booking. I'd like the ClientID and BookingID to be supplied by parameters from a form... I think I can manage that.

What I'm stuck on is using the Report Wizard to make this Invoice. In the wizard I choose all the columns from Clients and Booking. I tell it to group by client (kinda unnecessary because there will only be one client on the report at a time). In the wizard, the previews all look ok, but the final report comes out with Client and Booking info all in one really wide row.

What I'd like to do is separate the Client and Booking info, so that the "header" of the report shows the client name, address, etc, and the booking info is shown separately below.

How can I "break off" the booking columns and move them further down the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a report Group on [Client] then you can you can put the Client-specific fields in the group header (which should be called something like "Client Header") and then have the Booking fields in the Detail band of the report.